# Next.js output:standlone local server

Tags: next.js

I'm using output: "standalone" in nextConfig preparing for deployment.  When I run `node .next/standalone/server.js` locally I see the what's in the image below.  Using `next dev` produces expected `localhost:3000`.  Is there another setting needed? Or what is causing the server names to  do this?

[image]